# OWASP on Liferay7: external redirect error

Tags: redirect, liferay, owasp, liferay-7, zap

I've a Liferay community edition version 7.4.3.25-ga25 and I'm trying to analyze its security using OWASP ZAP tool.
I receive, among other things, an high level alert on external redirect which I do not understand. Here are the details:

- URL: https://my.liferay.it/c/portal/login?p_l_id=20184&windowState=8378327876640720401.owasp.org
- method: GET
- attack: 8378327876640720401.owasp.org
- evidence: 8378327876640720401.owasp.org
- Reference http://projects.webappsec.org/URL-Redirector-Abuse and http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/601.html
- CWE Id 601
- WASC Id 38
- Plugin Id 20019

I can't understand what type of attack it is this, the page does effectively a redirect but it remains on the same domain and login page, I've only more parameters on the URL bar.

I've searched the web but did non find any useful information. By the way, I do not control such Liferay behaviour, I've not made any customization to the framework which alters the login page behaviour.

Can someone help me to figure it out the problem? Thanks

Comment: I'd have to look at the code but I'm guessing that your response contains `location: https://my.liferay.it/c/portal/login?p_l_id=20184&windowState=8378327876640720401.owasp.org` since that contains the injected destination it's counting it as vuln. I'll have a look at it later and see if I'm correct.

Comment: This has been verified (assuming you're encountering what I explained above). I've submitted a PR to fix the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/pull/4116

Comment: that URL is the one that does the redirect. The redirection URL is `https://my.liferay.it/web/guest/home?p_p_id=com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=8378327876640720401.owasp.org&p_p_mode=view&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_mvcRenderCommandName=%2Flogin%2Flogin&saveLastPath=false`

Comment: ;) Added an answer for you, if you could accept it that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your response contains location: https://my.liferay.it/c/portal/login?p_l_id=20184&windowState=8378327876640720401.owasp.org since that contains the injected destination it's counting it as vuln.

I've submitted a fix to address this False Positive condition so that the checking is more restrictive.

After https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/pull/4116 is merged and the add-on re-released then you're example redirect `https://my.liferay.it/web/guest/home?p_p_id=com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=8378327876640720401.owasp.org&p_p_mode=view&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_mvcRenderCommandName=%2Flogin%2Flogin&saveLastPath=false` should no longer trigger an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ZAP Desktop?
If so then have a look to see if any requests are made to the owasp.org domain.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the desktop application. How do I check those requests? Are those listed on Ajax Spider tab?

Comment: You should see them in the Sites Tree.